# Select date range from two tables from present day to first day of that month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Using Microsoft SQL 2008. I have two tables that I want to select from the current date to the first day of that month (or within the same month). Let's say today's date is 05/09/2012 and the date column is 'datecolumn'. Fom the tables below I should only get rowsets 6,7 from table1 and rowsets 9,2 from table 2 because those dates are within the same month as 05/09/2012.

```
table1
4 02/01/2012
5 01/02/2011
6 05/01/2012
7 05/20/2012

table2
8 02/01/2012
9 05/14/2012
3 01/02/2011
2 05/18/2012
```

I tried this but it didnt work:

```
DECLARE @daterange
SET @daterange = (DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) + '/' + DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))

SELECT blah from table where (DATEPART(MONTH,datecolumn) + '/' + DATEPART(YEAR,datecolumn)) = @daterange
```

Comment: What if on table2 there's a row 10 with date of 5/15/2012. what will  be the output?

Comment: Indeed, if that is the case(matching all records in the month), no need to indicate range in title

Comment: The table will only produce dates for the day another stored procedure is ran. There won't be any future dates. Sorry if I confused anyone. I was trying to be sure that the rows returned were within the limits of that month and not to exceed the first or last of the month of the day the query was performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it, no need to reconstitute the date field from `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT blah
FROM table
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,datecolumn) = DATEPART(MONTH,getdate()) AND
DATEPART(YEAR,datecolumn) = DATEPART(YEAR,getdate())
```

Comment: You and Andriy had no difference in performance for the query. Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about determining the beginning and end of the current month, and then selecting for records between them:

```
declare @monthBeginning datetime 
set @monthBeginning = (select dateadd(dd,-(day(dateadd(mm,1,getdate()))-1),dateadd(mm,0,getdate()))

declare @monthEnd datetime
set @monthEnd = (select dateadd(dd, -day(dateadd(m,1,getdate())), dateadd(m,1,getdate())))

select *
from dateTable
where datecolumn between @monthBeginning and @monthEnd
```

If you find yourself using month beginning and ending calculations a lot, I'd recommend putting them into scalar functions - the logic is convoluted enough to not want to repeat it.

Comment: You forgot to put variable names into your assignment statements. Anyway, this seems somewhat overcomplicated, and you probably need to do something about the time parts (i.e. reset them to `00:00`).

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the first of the current month like this:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

By adding one month to the above result, you'll receive the first of the next month:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

Using those two dates, you can retrieve the required rows like this:

```
SELECT
  …
FROM table1
WHERE date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())    , 0)
  AND date <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. You and hkf had the same performance on the SQL statistics. You're code is great because it comes in handy for running balances (i.e. 3months, 6months ranges). Thanks again.